# Router Password Box Acting Strange?

Tags: networking

Trying to log into Verizon router and when I type in the password it shows more dots than I'm typing and then some randomly disappear halfway through.

Could this be why default of "admin" and "password" is not working

Comment: how are you trying to log in? web interface? have you tried another browser?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a malfunction of the keyboard, this is a "security feature" of the router. We are currently working with Verizon on how to properly log into the router with a screwy password box. Call Verizon and they should be able to walk you though it.

Answer (score 1):

Open up notepad or any text editor and try typing.

It sounds to me like something could be wrong with your keyboard, or you are using a funky addon (AutoHotKey, Text expanders etc.) which is malfunctioning.

Comment: It's not the keyboard. See "Cant get into Router" on this page: http://www.flaterco.com/kb/Fios.html